# Copying html into wordpress using a plugin causing problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress, jquery-ui

I used a plugin called embedit to use custom html, javascript and CSS in my wordpress. The original code look like:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <style>
    .calculator>td{
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    }
    input.dark[type=text] {
        transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        border-radius:8px;
        -webkit-border-radius:8px;
        -moz-border-radius:8px;
        border:1px solid rgba(31, 161, 5, 1);
        text-align: center;
    background: #000000;
    behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
        color: #10c90d;
        height: 20px;
        width: 35px;
    }
    #container { 
        width:300px;
        height:320px;
        z-index:4;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) skew(0,0) translate(0%,-5px);
        -moz-transform: rotate(10deg) skew(0,0) translate(0%,-5px);
        -o-transform: rotate(10deg) skew(0,0) translate(0%,-5px);
        transform: rotate(10deg) skew(0,0) translate(0%,-5px);

      font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    input[type=text].dark:focus {
        box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(31, 161, 5, 1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(31, 161, 5, 1); 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(31, 161, 5, 1);
    }
    .report{
        margin-top:-100px;
        margin-left:70%;
    }
    .main{
    background: rgb(0,155,5); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#9BD91A, #54750E); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(#9BD91A, #54750E); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#9BD91A, #54750E); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#9BD91A, #54750E); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#9BD91A, #54750E); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(#9BD91A, #54750E); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9BD91A', endColorstr='#54750E',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-width: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 21px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
     box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 21px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); 
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 21px 21px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); 
    width: 100%;
    }
    .pointer{
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .half{
    width: 50%;
    }
    .full{
    width: 100%;
    }

     .tape{
        position: relative;
        top:-40px;
        left:50px;
        width: 130px;
        height: 35px;
        background-color:#fff;
        opacity:0.6;
        border-left: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-right: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #cccccc;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #cccccc;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #cccccc;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg) skew(0,0) translate(0%,-5px);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg) skew(0,0) translate(0%,-5px);
        -o-transform: rotate(-2deg) skew(0,0) translate(0%,-5px);
        transform: rotate(-2deg) skew(0,0) translate(0%,-5px);
    }
    .paper {
        padding:25px 25px 40px;
        margin:0 auto 20px auto;
        align:center;   
        line-height:1.5;
        border:0;
        border-radius:3px;
        background: #F9EFAF;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
        background: linear-gradient(#F9EFAF, #F7E98D);
        box-shadow:0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        transition:box-shadow 0.5s ease;
        font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased;
        width:220px;
        height:260px;
    }
    .calculator{
      font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
      height: 700px;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="calculator">
    <div  class="main">
    <h1>Solar Payback Calculator</h1>
    <table>
    <form><tr><td colspan="9"><h2>Roof Size</h2></td></tr><tr><td>
    Width: </td><td class="pointer" onclick="subtractwidth();">-   </td><td colspan="2" width="500"><div id="slider1"></div></td><td class="pointer" onclick="addwidth();">   +    </td><td>
    Length: </td><td class="pointer" onclick="subtractlength();">-   </td><td colspan="2" width="500"><div id="slider2"></div></td><td class="pointer" onclick="addlength();">  
+</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td>
    <input type="text" id="roof_width" onKeyUp="calculate();" class="slider_input1 dark" value="0"/>m</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>
    <input type="text" id="roof_length" onKeyUp="calculate();" class="slider_input2 dark" value="0"/>m</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    Electricity Bill: </td><td class="pointer" onclick="subtractbill();">-   </td><td colspan="7" width="500"><div id="slider3"></div></td><td onclick="addbill();" class="pointer">  
+</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td>
    £<input type="text" id="electricity_bill" onKeyUp="calculate();" class="slider_input3 dark" value="0"/></td></tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    <table class="full"><tr><td>
    <table class="half">
    <tr><td>Area of the roof: </td><td></td><td><span id="roof_area"></span><span id="unit_area"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Number of Solar Panels: </td><td></td><td><span id="no_solar_panel"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>System Cost: </td><td></td><td><span id="system_cost"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Annual System Output: </td><td></td><td><span id="system_output"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>FIT Estimate: </td><td></td><td><span id="fit_estimate"></span></td></tr>
    </table></td>
    <td><table class="half">
    <tr><td>Export FiT: </td><td></td><td><span id="export_fit"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Savings from using Solar Energy: </td><td></td><td><span id="savings"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Total Annual Yields: </td><td></td><td><span id="total_annual_yield"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Payback time in years: </td><td></td><td><span id="payback_time"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Profit over 20 years: </td><td></td><td><span id="profit"></span></td></tr>
    </table></td></tr>
    </table>

    <script>
    $("#slider1").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        step: 0.01,
        min: 0,
        animate: true,
        max: 10,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".slider_input1" ).val( ui.value );
             calculate();
            //$( ".slider_input" ).val(  ui.value );
        }


       });


    $(".slider_input1").change(function () {
        var value = this.value
        $("#slider1").slider("value", parseInt(value));
                 calculate();
    });
    $("#slider2").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        step: 0.01,
        min: 0,
        animate: true,
        max: 10,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".slider_input2" ).val( ui.value );
             calculate();
            //$( ".slider_input" ).val(  ui.value );
        }


       });


    $(".slider_input2").change(function () {
        var value = this.value
        $("#slider2").slider("value", parseInt(value));
                 calculate();
    });
    $(".slider_input2").change(function () {
        var value = this.value
        $("#slider2").slider("value", parseInt(value));
                 calculate();
    });
    $("#slider3").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 0,
        step: 1,
        min: 0,
        animate: true,
        max: 3000,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( ".slider_input3" ).val( ui.value );
             calculate();
            //$( ".slider_input" ).val(  ui.value );
        }


       });


    $(".slider_input3").change(function () {
        var value = this.value
        $("#slider3").slider("value", parseInt(value));
                 calculate();
    });

    var calculate = function(){

    var roof_length = document.getElementById('roof_length').value;
    var roof_width = document.getElementById('roof_width').value;
    var electricity_bill= document.getElementById('electricity_bill').value;
    roof_length = parseInt(roof_length);
    roof_width = parseInt(roof_width);
    electricity_bill = parseInt(electricity_bill);
    if (roof_length<0 || roof_width<0 || electricity_bill<0){
    roof_length = Math.abs(roof_length);
    roof_width = Math.abs(roof_width);
    electricity_bill = Math.abs(electricity_bill);
    document.getElementById('roof_length').value=roof_length;
    document.getElementById('roof_width').value=roof_width;
    document.getElementById('electricity_bill').value=electricity_bill;
    }
    var roof_area = roof_length*roof_width;
    roof_area = roof_area.toFixed(2);
    if(isNaN(roof_area)){
    document.getElementById('roof_area').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    document.getElementById('unit_area').innerHTML="";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('roof_area').innerHTML=roof_area;
    document.getElementById('unit_area').innerHTML=" m<sup>2</sup>";
    }
    var no_solar_panel = roof_area/1.676675;
    no_solar_panel = Math.floor(no_solar_panel);
    if(isNaN(no_solar_panel)){
    document.getElementById('no_solar_panel').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else if(no_solar_panel<16){
    document.getElementById('no_solar_panel').innerHTML=no_solar_panel;
    }else{
    var no_solar_panel = 16;
    document.getElementById('no_solar_panel').innerHTML=no_solar_panel;
    }

    var system_cost = no_solar_panel*500;
    if(isNaN(system_cost)){
    document.getElementById('system_cost').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('system_cost').innerHTML="£" + system_cost;
    }

    var system_output = no_solar_panel*256;
    if(isNaN(system_output)){
    document.getElementById('system_output').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('system_output').innerHTML=system_output + " kWh";
    }

    var fit_estimate = (system_output*0.1544);
    fit_estimate = fit_estimate.toFixed(2);
    if(isNaN(fit_estimate)){
    document.getElementById('fit_estimate').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('fit_estimate').innerHTML="£" + fit_estimate;
    }
    var annual_electricity_used = electricity_bill/0.18;
    if(system_output>annual_electricity_used){
    var left_over = system_output-annual_electricity_used;
    left_over = left_over.toFixed(2);
    }else{
    var left_over = 0;
    }




    var export_fit = left_over*0.045;
    export_fit = export_fit.toFixed(2);
    if(isNaN(export_fit)){
    document.getElementById('export_fit').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('export_fit').innerHTML="£" + export_fit;
    }
    if(left_over>0){
    var savings = annual_electricity_used*0.18;
    savings = savings.toFixed(2);
    }else if(left_over<=0){
    var savings = system_output*0.18;
    savings = savings.toFixed(2);
    }

    if(isNaN(savings)){
    document.getElementById('savings').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('savings').innerHTML="£" + savings;
    }
    savings = parseInt(savings);
    fit_estimate = parseInt(fit_estimate);
    export_fit = parseInt(export_fit);
    var total_annual_yield = (savings+fit_estimate)+export_fit;
    if(isNaN(total_annual_yield)){
    document.getElementById('total_annual_yield').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('total_annual_yield').innerHTML="£" + total_annual_yield;
    }
    var payback_time = system_cost/total_annual_yield;
    payback_time = Math.ceil(payback_time);
    if(isNaN(payback_time)){
    document.getElementById('payback_time').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('payback_time').innerHTML=payback_time + " Years";
    }

    var profit = (total_annual_yield*20)-system_cost;

    if(isNaN(profit)){
    document.getElementById('profit').innerHTML="Invalid Input";
    }else{
    document.getElementById('profit').innerHTML="£" + profit;
    }
    if(isNaN(roof_width) || isNaN(roof_length) || isNaN(electricity_bill)){
    document.getElementById('report').innerHTML='<h1>Invalid Input</h1>';
    }else{

    document.getElementById('report').innerHTML='<div id="container"><div class="paper"><div class="tape"></div><h1>Report:</h1><span class="report-content">With your roof size of <span id="report_roof_area">_____</span> m<sup>2</sup>, you can fit <span id="report_no_solar_panel">_____</span> solar panels for £<span id="report_system_cost">_____</span>.<br />Saving you £<span id="report_savings">____</span> each year on your bill!<br />Making £<span id="report_total_annual_yield">_____</span> each year and £<span id="report_profit">____</span> profit over 20 years.</span></div><!--end paper--></div><!--end container-->';
    document.getElementById('report_roof_area').innerHTML=roof_area;
    document.getElementById('report_no_solar_panel').innerHTML=no_solar_panel;
    document.getElementById('report_system_cost').innerHTML=system_cost;
    document.getElementById('report_savings').innerHTML=savings;
    document.getElementById('report_total_annual_yield').innerHTML=total_annual_yield;
    document.getElementById('report_profit').innerHTML=profit;
    }
    }



    var subtractwidth = function(){

    var roof_width = document.getElementById('roof_width').value;
    roof_width = parseInt(roof_width);
    var roof_width = roof_width-1;
    document.getElementById('roof_width').value=roof_width;
    }
    var addwidth = function(){
    var roof_width = document.getElementById('roof_width').value;
    roof_width = parseInt(roof_width);
    var roof_width = roof_width+1;
    document.getElementById('roof_width').value=roof_width;
    calculate();
    }
    var subtractlength = function(){
    var roof_length = document.getElementById('roof_length').value;
    roof_length = parseInt(roof_length);
    var roof_length = roof_length-1;
    document.getElementById('roof_length').value=roof_length;
    calculate();
    }
    var addlength = function(){
    var roof_length = document.getElementById('roof_length').value;
    roof_length = parseInt(roof_length);
    var roof_length = roof_length+1;
    document.getElementById('roof_length').value=roof_length;
    calculate();
    }
    var subtractbill = function(){
    var electricity_bill= document.getElementById('electricity_bill').value;
    electricity_bill = parseInt(electricity_bill);
    var electricity_bill = electricity_bill-10;
    document.getElementById('electricity_bill').value=electricity_bill;
    calculate();
    }
    var addbill = function(){
    var electricity_bill= document.getElementById('electricity_bill').value;
    electricity_bill = parseInt(electricity_bill);
    var electricity_bill = electricity_bill+10;
    document.getElementById('electricity_bill').value=electricity_bill;
    calculate();
    }
    document.getElementById('roof_length').value=0;
    document.getElementById('roof_width').value=0;
    document.getElementById('electricity_bill').value=0;
    </script>


















    </div>
    <div class="report" id="report">
    <div id="container"><div class="paper"><div class="tape"></div><h1>Please Input Values</h1></div><!--end paper--></div><!--end container-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Without wordpress it looks like: http://www.asifslab.com/solarpanel.html
But when I add it to wordpress it looks like: bit.ly/Yvn2vv
The jquery-ui slider unfortunately does not work, and the style is in a complete mess.
Moreover the html do not fit into the content area(the report covers the footer).
How to fix this problem. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS of your wordpress site is applying to the custom HTML code you added using the plugin, that's why the styles are all messed up, and also probably why the sliders are not working (i didn't verify that point).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a plugin, use an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.asifslab.com/solarpanel.html">
```

And apply some styling.  (Adjust these to fit your needs.)

```
iframe { 
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 600px;
    display: block;
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/haSf4/1/)

To clarify what your problem is; you have two sets of styles that weren't made with each other in mind.  So there are issues with Wordpress overriding the styles on your widget.  Putting it in an iframe keeps everything separate, so that the widget doesn't affect the blog styles, and the blog doesn't affect the widget.  Harmony.

Comment: I also thought of using iFrame but I heard its recommended not to us it

Comment: It's there for a reason, and this is that reason (maybe you're thinking of `frame`, which is outdated and not recommended).

Answer (score 0):

AS gotson said, the css from your wordpress theme overrides some of the things on your custom page. You may want to use a unique class with a prefix instead of using a general tag and create it in a fix width container that is the same with the wordpress template that you're using.

```
#sp_Container{ //apply style }
```

Instead of

```
#container{ //apply style }
```

also, make sure to target every declaration inside that container.

```
#sp_Container .class1{ //apply style }
#sp_Container .class2{ //apply style }
#sp_Container .class3{ //apply style }
```

P.S. The container needs a position:relative; so you can make sure that the result note won't get too far from it(if it was set on a position:absolute;).

Comment: Make sure there's no conflict on your script. I saw 51 errors via Chrome's inspect element terminal. (Sorry can't debug it for you)